# Exporting Blender model in unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So I make some basic map in blender and I want to export it in unity project where I can play on it.
but it looks bad really bad, soo how to fix this? [image: Blender] [image: Unity]
sorry for low quality images.

Comment: It's all about material/shader/postprocessing. Brackeys' videos are good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your normals are orientated correctly in blender. Unity culls all faces that point away from the camera.
You can do this in blender by using the "Recalculate normals" tool. To make sure all your faces are pointing outward, you can enable visualizations in blender like this:
[image: Check normals]
If you find any of these indicators pointing the wrong way, select this face and use the "Flip Normals" tool to flip any remaining inverted faces.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Kts42Si
same problem other project. normals are in right spot but in unity it shows like this
https://imgur.com/6FidmlP
https://imgur.com/iGhlh4j

Comment: @ChiperChiper Seeing as your model is skinned/has a skeleton, have you tried applying transformations to both your skeleton and model? CTRL+A in pose mode and object mode for each respectively?